# MongoDB: change each item in an array into an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am learning MongoDB and trying to update each item in an array stored in each document in my collection. So my documents have the following format:

```
{_id:...,
 name:'...', 
 image: '...',
 devices: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3',...]
}
```

What I want to do is take each item in the devices array and turn them into an object like this:

```
devices:[{item1:'imagepath'},{item2:'imagepath'},{item3:'imagepath'}]
```

I tried running the following code in the MongoDB shell but nothing happens. I don't get an error or anything. When I check the collection, the device array hasn't been update.

```
db.airforce.find().forEach(function (obj1) {
    obj1.devices.forEach(function(device){
            db.airforce.update({},{
                $set:{
                    "devices.[device]":{device:'images/devices/' + device + '.png'}
                }
            })
        }
    )
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- create one variable called `devices` and push your image path device wise
- assign `devices` to `obj1.devices`
- `save()` to save whole document

```
db.airforce.find().forEach(function (obj1) {
    let devices = [];
    obj1.devices.forEach(function (device){
        devices.push({[device]: 'images/devices/' + device + '.png'});           
    })
    obj1.devices = devices;
    db.airforce.save(obj1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$map` to modify the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      devices: {
        $map: {
          input: "$devices",
          in: {
            item: "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PNNOUBBQtAs)**